# Grid Control Standby database status: Creation status unknown

Tags: oracle, dataguard

After using Grid Control to add standby database, Data Guard status of standby database is showing "Creation status unknown". However, dataguard status on both primary and standby databases are OK. Database is Oracle 11.2.0.3. The Management agent version is 12.1.0.1. 
I read on [the forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1108702?start=0&tstart=0) that I need to apply patch #9244383. However, when I apply patch, It requires agent version 10.2.0.5.

What should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a MOSC note, and while it's specific to versions 10.2.0.1 to 10.2.0.5, maybe it worths testing.

The note states that when creating Standby using grid, there were some issues and the remaining part of its creation was done manually.

The recommendation is to remove the Standby DB from the Grid in order to clear the errors, and then rediscover the Standby DB.

For complete reference: Doc ID 1455165.1

Comment: I removed the DG configuration then added standby database again. Now status is back to normal. Cheers